# CSS > Trying to style a button - there must be an easier way

Tags: css

Here is my CSS

```
  .button-1 {
    background-color: #f7f1e3;
    border: none;
    color: #393939;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family:Montserrat;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
  }


  .button-1:hover {
    background-color: #aaa69d;
    color: #393939;
  }
```

And here is the HTML

```
  <button class="button-1">
    <a href="">Click Me</a>
  </button>
```

So, there's nothing at all complicated here but I have got stuck on the most efficient way to add a basic HREF tag for a link.

If I add a simple link in the text area of the button then I get the generic styles.

Now, of course, I can create a CSS A Class for the button but I have several of these and it is just going to create a lot more code.

My question is: what's the most efficient way? Can I not just add the Link Class to the button-1 CSS directly?

Thanks!

Comment: That’s not even valid HTML to begin with, you can not put an `a` into a `button`, they are _both_ “interactive” elements, and as such can not be nested in this way. Do you want a button to trigger some (JavaScript) action, or do you want to _link_ to some other URL? Based on that, you should chose _either_ a button, _or_ a link.

Comment: I just want the button to send to a URL upon click. Thanks for help

Comment: So you want a normal link, and _format_ it to look like a button. So `<button>` should not be involved here _at all_, remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be specific, you should make a new selector to `<a>` element inside the button:

```
.button-1 a{}
```

also, if you want to remove all "generic styles" from your `<a>` tags you can create generic selector for links.

```
a{
  color:inherit,
  text-decoration: none
}
```

or even a `*` selector for all elements

```
*{
  color:inherit,
  text-decoration: none
}
```

**PD:** If you add padding style to button element and inside of this a `<a>` element, the padding area won't be clickable for link, I recommend you to add padding to `<a>` element.